Flink Data Stream fromDataStream to Table converts java.util.Map Kafka headers to RAW
My particular use case is reading from a Table backed by Kafka, converting to a data stream, performing an operation, converting back to a table, and writing to an output Kafka topic. Headers are included and passed though to the output table, but the Map containing them is converted to RAW('java.util.Map', '...') in the StreamTableEnvironment.fromDataStream() which causes type mismatch errors. I put together a very simple test job that doesn't do any conversions.
Both the input and output tables define the headers as headers MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA.
The StreamTableEnvironment.toDataStream() correctly converts the headers to a java.util.Map<String,byte[]>.
I've tried adding @DataTypeHint annotations, specifying the schema in the fromDataStream() call, and explicitly casting, but those always produce unable to cast errors.
According to the documentation, java.util.Map should automatically be converted to a MAP type.
Here's my test job definition.
        Table inputTable = streamTableEnv.from(inputTableName);
        var entryRowStream = streamTableEnv.toDataStream(inputTable, EntryRow.class);

        var mappedRowStream = entryRowStream.map(row -> row); //do some operation

        Table outputTable = streamTableEnv.fromDataStream(mappedRowStream);

        streamTableEnv.createStatementSet().add(outputTable.insertInto(outputTableName))
                .attachAsDataStream();
        streamEnv.executeAsync("Table Datastream test");

EntryRow
public class EntryRow {
   field1 String;
   @DataTypeHint(value = "MAP<STRING, BYTES>")
   Map<String,byte[]> headers;
   public EntryRowV065() {}
}

Interestingly, if the single identity map operation is removed, then it works without any issues. But as soon as any operation is performed on the stream, it runs into this type conversion problem.
I'm using Flink 1.17.2.

I was able to find a work around by creating a UDF that mapped the raw type to SQL. It's very simple, but still not sure why this is even needed.
public class MapCastFunction extends ScalarFunction {
    public static Map<String, byte[]> eval(@DataTypeHint(value = "RAW", bridgedTo = Map.class) Map value) {
        return (Map<String,byte[]>)value;
    }
}

